# Using location manager

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I want to do the following

- Track location in the background in the APP Delegate File
- Track someone's location in the View Controller.

Here is how I am doing it:

in APPDelegate:

in applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
{
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    _startLocation = nil;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter=500;
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    // Set Property
    self.myLocation = newLocation;

    BOOL isInBackground = NO;
    if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground)
    {
        isInBackground = YES;
    }

    // Handle location updates as normal, code omitted for brevity.
    // The omitted code should determine whether to reject the location update for being too
    // old, too close to the previous one, too inaccurate and so forth according to your own
    // application design.

    if (isInBackground)
    {
        [self sendBackgroundLocationToServer:newLocation];
    }

    if(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= 100.0f)
    {
        [self.locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    }
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if(self.locationManager == nil)
    {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    }
    [self.locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    self.locationManager = nil;
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    [self.locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

in The ViewController:

```
- (void) startLocationChanges {

    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        PLAppDelegate *appDelegate = (PLAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        if(appDelegate.locationManager == nil)
        {
            self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        }
        else {
            self.locationManager = appDelegate.locationManager;
        }

        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}


- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    self.myLocation = newLocation;

    [self uploadLocationCoordinates];


    if(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= 100.0f)
    {
        NSLog(@"stop updating location");

        [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }

    //_horizontalAccuracy.text = currentHorizontalAccuracy;
}
```

Am I doing this the right way? It seems location services is still on when someone closes the app.

Answer (score 2):

From a design point of view, I find it best to keep the location manager wrapped in a singleton class ([example](http://jinru.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/singletons-in-objective-c-an-example-of-cllocationmanager/)). What you're doing here:

```
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
{
    PLAppDelegate *appDelegate = (PLAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if(appDelegate.locationManager == nil)
    {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    }
    else {
        self.locationManager = appDelegate.locationManager;
    }

    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

...is quite messy: you may be copying the location manager object or just referencing it (and the code isn't clear on what's happening there without seeing the header file) and you generally shouldn't switch the delegate of the location manager around.

Using a singleton class will give you a single place to deal with location-related things, and your view controllers and other classes can ask for this data whenever they want. Alternatively, you could use the delegate pattern to store a reference to every location-aware class (e.g. view controller, app delegate) in the singleton, and broadcast to those classes when you get a callback such as `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation`.

I hope that helps - have a look at the link I added to see what I mean: the singleton pattern is the perfect thing to use here since you'll only ever want one source of location data to be used at any one time.

Comment: Also, you can detect when your application is going into the background in the app delegate, and then stop monitoring for location updates. See the information about application state changes here: You can detect when your app goes into the background with the application delegate methods `willResignActive`, etc. You can read more about application state changes here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIApplicationDelegate

Comment: I am following your tutorial here:http://jinru.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/singletons-in-objective-c-an-example-of-cllocationmanager/#comment-85 Where do you put the [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation]

Comment: You can put it wherever you know you'll want to start receiving location updates. For example you could put it in the `sharedInstance` method in the tutorial just after `[[self alloc] init]` so that it starts receiving updates as soon as the singleton is first requested.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine, but if you've registered for location changes it'll remain active in the background. If you want to suspend the location changes there's a couple of ways, I generally stop them in my `AppDelegate`.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
   NSLog(@"Application entering background");
   CLLocationManager *locMan = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
   [locMan stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
   [locMan stopUpdatingLocation];
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    CLLocationManager *locMan = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locMan startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If u are closing the app by pressing center button in iphone then this method gets called

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Comment: Did you mean applicationWillEnterBackground? I think you have it the other way around. applicationWillEnterForeground is called right before the app RETURNS from the background